# Printing all even or odd numbers up to given N

Tags: c++, recursion

So I have to write a **recursive** function printOddEven(int n), which checks wheter n is even or odd and depending on it it prints out all even or odd numbers up to n (for n=6 its 2 4 6 and for n=7 its 1 3 5 7). The closest I got to it is to make a function printOddEven(int st, int n) with such code:

```
void printOddEven(int st, int n){   
    if (st > n){return;}
    cout << st << " ";
    printOddEven(st+2, n);
}
```

However I was told to keep this function dependant of just n and I have no clue how it should look like. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: If `n > 0`, do the recursive call with (`n-2`) as argument. Then print `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct, you just need to iterate backwards from `n`, and make the recursive call before you print so that the prints are in the correct order.

Based on your attempt:

```
void printOddEven(int n){   
    if (n < 1) { return; }
    printOddEven(n-2);
    cout << n << " ";
}
```